# How to contain a directory (example.com/dir) in Apache conf's Servername setting?

Tags: apache, hosting

In Apache conf's Servername setting, I need to specify a directory.

Such as Servername www.example.com/directory. I trid and it does not work, though.

I have a main site (www.example.com) which documentroot is /var/www/html/main and my sub site URL is www.example.com/sub and its documentroot is /var/www/html/sub.

Thank you.

Comment: Please consider answering some of your open questions - I count six unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.example.com/directory` is not a valid value for `ServerName`. Only hostname and port can be included in the value for `ServerName`.

What you want to define is called an `Alias`.  You can [read about `Alias` here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

For example, inside of your configuration for `www.example.com`, you can add this line:

`Alias /sub /var/www/html/sub`